# vb.net require assignment on declaration

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to require that an object class be assigned a value in its declaration?

For example, if I have:

```
Dim MyObject As New Library.ObjectClass
MyObject = FunctionThatReturnsObject(Parameter)
```

Can I change ObjectClass so that it can't be declared with "New", and MUST be used as:

```
Dim MyObject As Library.ObjectClass = FunctionThatReturnsObject(Parameter)
```

I understand that I could just build a constructor for ObjectClass that calls FunctionThatReturnsObject, but I keep having instances of ObjectClass being totally empty because I absentmindedly declare them without assigning them.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @Plutonix “you will always need New though to create the object” — not really, you can make `New` `Private` (or `Protected`) and indeed that’s often a good idea. The constructor still exists, but it can’t be called directly by the user, the user has to use a builder function instead.

Comment: Yes, I was confusing myself depending on how you want to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent this?

Not entirely. One thing you can do is make the constructor `Private`, and instead offer a `Public Shared` function returning a constructed object. This is sometimes a useful thing to do, but it doesn’t solve your actual problem: ensuring that every object of your type is properly initialised.

Because VB default-initialises all declared (but not initialised) objects, there’s no way to enforce a different initialisation.

However, the example code you’ve posted doesn’t really make sense anyway: it’s trivial to prevent the following code:

```
Dim MyObject As New Library.ObjectClass
MyObject = FunctionThatReturnsObject(Parameter)
```

Simply declare a constructor that takes parameters, or make the constructor private. That will prevent the user from using `New ObjectClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a shared function defined on the class. The shared function will have access to the private members of the same class. The only way to get a new MyObject would be from calling `MyClass.FunctionThatReturnsObject()`

```
Public Class MyClass

    Private _parameter As String

    Private Sub New()


    End Sub

    Private Sub New(parameter As String)
        _parameter = parameter
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function FunctionThatReturnsObject() As MyClass

        Dim myObject As New MyClass("a parameter")

        'Or you could manipulate the private paraemters directly...
        'myObject._parameter = "a parameter"
        Return myObject

    End Function

End Class
```